# Rotating of large image causes OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, image-processing

I'm trying to rotate the image taken from camera and save it without scaling down without showing in an view, but when I try to load it like this

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tmpImageFilePath);
```

I get OutOfMemoryError. There is no problem for me to rotate image but how to load it and save with original size? I've already googled some techniques in order to solve this problem but none of them fits me.

And when I try this variant:

```
 File f = new File(tmpImageFilePath);
                long filesize = f.length();
                ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(f.getPath());
                int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

                int angle = 0;

                if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
                    angle = 90;
                }
                else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
                    angle = 180;
                }
                else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
                    angle = 270;
                }

                Matrix mat = new Matrix();
                mat.postRotate(angle);
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 8;
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tmpImageFilePath, options);    
                Bitmap correctBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), mat, true);
                bmp.recycle();
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
                    correctBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I get lesser image.

Comment: If you want to rotate images taken by camera only then try playing with `Camera.setDisplayOrientation` [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29)

Comment: I am forced to use native camera app, which uses different camera orientations dependent on producer (for example Motorola uses landscape while HTC uses portrait)